# Mouse defect, faulty ceramic capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, repair, mouse

The right button of my optical mouse is not beeing recognised anymore so i decided to take the mouse apart and search for the error.

My mouse is nearly the same as the one mentioned in [this question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/65021/help-identifying-and-finding-shematics-datasheets-for-circuit-board)

While searching for the possible error I found a [ceramic capacitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdhaU.jpg) which is fully covered in a white, crusty coating. The ceramic capacitor in front has also a few white covered areas. One is connected between USB data+ and ground and the other one between USB data- and ground. Could this be the error and what happened to those 2 capacitors?

[image: photo]

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: Unlikely to affect only a button. Problems with caps connected to the USB D+ and D- are likely to block communications to the entire mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you left handed? with buttons reversed?  The primary button is often  the 1st one to fail, either by case fatigue or solder joint failure.

- If mechanical alignment, the tactile click feel will be missing and mechanical stretching is needed.
- If electrical, then check switch with ohmmeter and solder connection.

The white powder is a sign of previous component failure from internal partial short circuit , over heating oozing out of molten ceramic binder, followed by  slow cooling down after fusing open the internal partial shorts to allow the crystals to grow.

The external white crystals on ceramic discs are made from aluminum oxide, aluminum nitride, magnesium oxide, and silicon dioxide.

- A sign of poor quality ceramic caps.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely the micro switch associated with the right button.

[image]

Micro switches are inexpensive.  However finding one of the correct dimensions will likely take some effort.  All that said, unless this is one expensive mouse, it would be easier to simply buy a new mouse and keep this one for a future project or parts.